# Why Java not force us to override equals and hashcode when we have a custom implementation of both

Tags: java

I had a class which I was using as source of equality, and then someone new in the team modify the equals but not the hashcode, that cause some problems, so why the Java or the IDE at least throws a warning indicating that should not be what we want to do, so there should be a reason to not doing so I am looking for that explanation

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary overhead that you're requiring for even one-off classes, such as anonymous inner listener classes

Comment: Also, note that the methods ***are*** required but are thankfully supplied in a default fashion by the Object class.

Comment: The default implementations of equals and hashCode implement the requirements perfectly. Why should you be forced to replace them?

Comment: Not every class is a data class.  You wouldn’t try to compare two `Thread` instances, would you?

Comment: Maybe I can refrase my question to when you need a custom implementation the IDE do not at least warning that you "forget" to override one or the other in order to avoid problems, maybe there is the case you did the override ok but someone modify and Just override one, is more like that scenario my question is related

Comment: If you use the IDE to generate code blocks, "equals and hashcode" is an option in IntelliJ. There aren't warnings for several reasons including the ones above. The default implementations satisfy for reference equality, if you only change equals but not hashcode then you cause problems with classes that rely on that relationship (e.g. hashed structures like HashMap). Let's be clear: #hashCode _exists_ to support these classes. If you're not intending them for a hashed data structure (_numerous_ classes), then why force it? Especially back when it was introduced and code generation was scant

Comment: @jam given you can put entirely arbitrary code in the bodies of these two methods, it's actually rather hard to determine whether they are implemented consistently.

Comment: Yes I understand but my point is that we had a valid scenario for override those methods and then someone else modify one method instead of both, and causing troubles at the end we as programmers need to try detect those scenarios but I think this error is very easily to replicate and will continue happen again and again,  but all the suggestion that mention in the comments are good points to consider

Comment: _"someone else modify one method instead of both"_ — your Unit Test for the class should have caught that issue.

Comment: @StephenP you have a point and I can assure you there was unit test, but the test wasn't a real production scenario where we can have a lot of object in a hash and depending there were no collitions between the hashcode(by this point were not equals), and this is my point, is like if you try to use findAny vs findFirst, the documentation state that one is deterministic and the other no and most of the time it will return the same, the same happen here at the end I think its difficult to test and easily to make that mistake but the original question was answered in some of the comments

Comment: @jam, do not expect others have to know as much as you, just give them enough document just over and inside the methods they have to be careful when they are doing their jobs.